# multiplayer game + flashs new p2p technology + dedicated server

Tags: apache-flex, flash, dedicated-server

im planning on making a flash multiplayer game with using the kinda new p2p features of flash.
my question is: is it possible to add a option for players to host a game on their own root server for better connection? or is it impossible to host a flash server without a gui on a linux root?

sorry for that beginner question!

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible to add a option for
>   players to host a game on their own
>   root server for better connection?

Why do you think this would not be possible?

I'm sure they'd have to install some server to make it happen, I assume; whether something you provided or something like [GraniteDS](http://www.graniteds.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=229378) or [Red5](http://red5.org/) (or Flash Media Server or LiveCycle) or some other application server software.  I'm sure there are ones out there designed specifically for games.

I doubt most "normal" game users have the chops to setup servers [or even linux], but it depends what your target market for the game is.

> or is it impossible to host a flash
>   server without a gui on a linux root?

I don't see why you couldn't do this.  All versions of Apache Iv'e used are, esentially, GUI-less and they run fine on Linux.  Conceptually it isn't much different with any other server.  Of course, I probably wouldn't throw such responsibilities to the 'layman' gamer.

Answer (score 0):

The whole purpose of p2p is distributed network. You don't need a server.
The problem with Flash p2p is that it is bound on Adobe Stratus which is hosted by Adobe. It is used to actually "connect" p2p peers together. This functionality should be available in a next FMS release so you could use FMS to host a "server" for p2p network.